# Traducción de 'helpful' en encuesta de satisfacción

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

En una encuesta de satisfacción de atención al cliente de una tienda online aparece la palabra **'helpful'**. Esta compañía ha traducido esta palabra al castellano como **'servicial'**:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

¿Pensáis que, en este contexto, **'servicial'** es la mejor traducción de **'helpful'** ?

**=== Edited 2018 =======================================**

Por lo visto, la empresa, ha corregido el texto:

[image]

Comment: Por lo que veo, la página tiene dominio .es luego es de España. Sin embargo, a mí no me suena demasiado bien y algo así como _de ayuda_ me encaja mejor. ¿Qué te parece a ti? A todo esto, bienvenido/a a [spanish.se] :)

Comment: Hola @fedorqui, **grep master** gracias por acogerme :) A mi me 'servicial' me suena fatal.

Comment: @fedorqui aunque el dominio sea .es, se nota que es amazon, y obviamente es una página traducida de su versión original :p 
danihp: buen intento al esconder los iconos jeje

Comment: [Ayudador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4cMRErA) existe, pero suena peor que "servicial".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En mi opinión, no.
Una persona puede ser [servicial](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=servicial) sin serme **de [ayuda](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=4cL8wGW)** en absoluto; y, de igual manera, una persona puede ser de gran ayuda sin comportarse de manera servicial.

Como habrás adivinado, te propongo la expresión "**de ayuda**" como traducción:

> ¿Le fue de ayuda el representante de Jineta?
>
> - De muy poca o ninguna ayuda.
> - De poca ayuda.
> - Ni mucha ni poca ayuda.
> - De alguna ayuda.
> - De mucha ayuda.

---

Otra opcion sería cambiar la pregunta por **¿Está usted satisfecho con la ayuda recibida por el representante de ...?**, siendo las opciones: muy poco o nada satisfecho, poco satisfecho, etc; aunque tiene la pega de que no es neutral en cuanto a género.

Comment: ¿'Jineta'? Ja ja ja.

Comment: Muy bien.  También: "La llamada con el representante le sirvió a resolver su problema?"  Sí, mucho, Sí, un poco, etc.

Comment: @walen - Sí, creo también, gracias.  O "le sirvió en algo" quizás también.

Answer (score 5):

A mi `servicial` tampoco me parece la mejor opción. No solo no suena del todo bien al oído, si no que, [como apunta Walen en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21726/5481), tiene el significado de "Que sirve con cuidado, diligencia y obsequio" en el sentido de "Estar al servicio de alguien; Hacer lo que alguien dispone."

Yo habría intentado usar "[útil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bCSFzkP%7CbCTJISY)" o "[provechoso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UTUonKT)", pero tampoco terminan de cuadrar, ya que el representante es una persona, y decir

> ¿Le fue útil el representante?

Es casi convertirle en objeto.

Podría intentarse usar los términos

> [**Solícito**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YI3otXt)
>
> adj. Diligente, cuidadoso.

o

> [**Acomedido**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0X2Qs5m)
>
> adj. Chile, Ec., Guat., Hond., Méx., Nic., Pan., Perú y R. Dom. Servicial, oficioso.

Pero una vez más tendrías que darle un poco la vuelta a la frase, y decir

> ¿Fue *solícito* el representante?
>
> ¿Fue *acomedido* el representante?

suena también raro. Al final, uno termina diciendo "esto no mejora casi *servicial*!!" y terminaría usando `servicial` como el original o preguntando simplemente

> ¿(Le) Fue *de ayuda* el representante?

Quizá no sea la *mejor* opción, pero es la "menos mala" que yo he podido encontrar!

Comment: Diego, tu respuesta és muy elaborada y clara. Walen contestó primero, acumuló más puntos y los dos llegáis a la misma conclusión. Os he +1 a los dos y acepto su respuesta. Gracias por tu disertación!